# Is “When you exit the gate, on the right hand side, a homeless person is there” a well formed sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, ambiguity

Settling a debate about the following sentence:

**“When you exit the gate, on the right hand side, a homeless person is there.”**

The sentence was spoken verbally, if that changes things.

I feel that at the very least the middle clause is ambiguous regarding what it’s being applied to. Spoken verbally I would contend most would assume the sentence is referring to “exiting the gate on the right hand side.” Additionally I’d say the sentence is simply badly formed.

My dissenter claims that the sentence is well formed and that it is unambiguous that the sentence is referring to a homeless person on the right hand side that is present upon exiting the gate.

Looking for a third party opinion. Thanks!

Comment: It is perfectly clear what it means but it is rather awkwardly phrased.

Comment: The sentences is certainly NOT well formed. Whether it makes much difference whether you exit the gate on the right hand side or you will find the homeless person on the righthand side is moot.

Comment: "When you exit the gate, you'll see a homeless person on the right-hand side." The person 'being there' is a fact; it's not dependent on the addressee walking out of the gate.

Comment: Yes, being spoken English could potentially clear up any ambiguity here.  Intonation often makes a huge difference.  What was the exact intonation used when this was said? Are the commas placed correctly, or did you just place them there?   Do you have a sample of the audio which we can listen to?

Answer (score 0):

The punctuation is intended to make clear that "on the right hand side" indicates the position of the homeless person, not the location of the gate.

In spoken English this would be achieved by intonation and may not be clear.  So in spoken English there is greater possibility to be misunderstood than in written English.

So what is "ambiguity".  If it is the possibility that a listener might misunderstand, then there is ambiguity.

It is not helped by the rather odd narrative. Ambiguity is reduced when the wider context is clear as we understand in context.  Here it is not clear why you would say this.